Adding multiple range in 1 seclection
I need to add 2 range in 1 selection
Here is my code trying to add a new range to a current selection
<p id="p">Select me: <i>italic</i> and <b>bold</b></p>

Cloned: <span id="cloned"></span>
<br>
As text: <span id="astext"></span>
<div><button id="check"></button></div>


<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("check").addEventListener('click', () => {
      Selection = window.getSelection();
      let newR = new Range();
      newR.setStart(p.firstChild, 2);
      newR.setEnd(p.firstChild, 6);
      console.log(Selection);

      Selection.addRange(newR);
      console.log(Selection);
      cloned.append(Selection.rangeCount.toString());
      astext.innerHTML += Selection.toString();
    });
  }
</script>

The problem is that if I don't select anything, the selection will include my new range. However, if I select something, it seems to ignore the addRange function.Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

According to Selection: addRange() method : Currently only Firefox supports multiple selection ranges, other browsers will not add new ranges to the selection if it already contains one.
